# Jump to a specific part of a page but doesn't show up at top of the browser window

Tags: html, hyperlink, anchor

I can create a link to jump to a specific section like [this](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/html/how-to-create-an-anchor-link-to-jump-to-a-specific-part-of-a-page.html):

```
<h3 id="summary"> Summary:  </h3>
<a href="#summary"> Go to the conclusions </a>
```

and it works.
But I found that if the summary section is near the end of a document page and
cannot fill the whole window,
it will be bottom-justified or aligned. Then the browser will show the
section in the middle of the window rather than at the top. I sometimes have to resize
the window smaller to fix the problem.

Is there a way to make the anchored element always show up at the top?

@Basta, this is now after clicking the link:
[image]

and this is what I was expecting where Summary is at the top:
[image]

Comment: if there's no page to scroll to, then no. Only solution would be to add extra white space after that section to fill at least 100 viewport height

Comment: Can you please show us how it looks like now and how you want it to be